# Regex: how to determine odd/even number of occurrences of a char preceding a given char?

Tags: regex

I would like to replace the `|` with `OR` only in unquoted terms, eg:

```
"this | that" | "the | other" -> "this | that" OR "the | other"
```

Yes, I could split on space or quote, get an array and iterate through it, and reconstruct the string, but that seems ... inelegant.  So perhaps there's a regex way to do this by counting `"`s preceding `|` and obviously odd means the `|` is quoted and even means unquoted.  (Note: Processing doesn't start until there is an even number of `"` if there is at least one `"`).

Comment: Regex don't do that. Regex libraries that do that use algorithms that are not based on regular expressions, and can't guarantee the same efficiency. Sinan's answer is based on the observation that the pipe characters you want to change always appear between two quotes, and the pipe characters you don't want to change never do. It's a good solution, if valid. Otherwise, give up regex.

Comment: The text of the question has an answer. The title of the question does not.

Answer (score 13):

It's true that regexes can't count, but they *can* be used to determine whether there's an odd or even number of something.  The trick in this case is to examine the quotation marks *after* the pipe, not before it.

```
str = str.replace(/\|(?=(?:(?:[^"]*"){2})*[^"]*$)/g, "OR");
```

Breaking that down, `(?:[^"]*"){2}` matches the next pair of quotes if there is one, along with the intervening non-quotes.  After you've done that as many times as possible (which might be zero), `[^"]*$` consumes any remaining non-quotes until the end of the string.

Of course, this assumes the text is well-formed.  It doesn't address the problem of escaped quotes either, but it can if you need it to.

Answer (score 5):

Regexes do not count.  That's what parsers are for.

Comment: Yes, this problem screams for a state machine.

Answer (score 4):

You might find the [Perl FAQ on this issue](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlfaq6.html#Can-I-use-Perl-regular-expressions-to-match-balanced-text%3f) relevant.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;

my $x = qq{"this | that" | "the | other"};
print join('" OR "', split /" \| "/, $x), "\n";
```

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to count, because you don't nest quotes. This will do:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

my $str = '" this \" | that" | "the | other" | "still | something | else"';
print "$str\n";

while($str =~ /^((?:[^"|\\]*|\\.|"(?:[^\\"]|\\.)*")*)\|/) {
        $str =~ s/^((?:[^"|\\]*|\\.|"(?:[^\\"]|\\.)*")*)\|/$1OR/;
}

print "$str\n";
```

Now, let's explain that expression.

```
^  -- means you'll always match everything from the beginning of the string, otherwise
      the match might start inside a quote, and break everything

(...)\|   -- this means you'll match a certain pattern, followed by a |, which appears
             escaped here; so when you replace it with $1OR, you keep everything, but
             replace the |.

(?:...)*  -- This is a non-matching group, which can be repeated multiple times; we
             use a group here so we can repeat multiple times alternative patterns.

[^"|\\]*  -- This is the first pattern. Anything that isn't a pipe, an escape character
             or a quote.

\\.       -- This is the second pattern. Basically, an escape character and anything
             that follows it.

"(?:...)*" -- This is the third pattern. Open quote, followed by a another
              non-matching group repeated multiple times, followed by a closing
              quote.

[^\\"]    -- This is the first pattern in the second non-matching group. It's anything
             except an escape character or a quote.

\\.       -- This is the second pattern in the second non-matching group. It's an
             escape character and whatever follows it.
```

The result is as follow:

```
" this \" | that" | "the | other" | "still | something | else"
" this \" | that" OR "the | other" OR "still | something | else"
```

Answer (score 1):

Another approach (similar to Alan M's working answer):

```
str = str.replace(/(".+?"|\w+)\s*\|\s*/g, '$1 OR ');
```

The part inside the first group (spaced for readability):

```
".+?"  |  \w+
```

... basically means, something quoted, or a word.  The remainder means that it was followed by a "|" wrapped in optional whitespace.  The replacement is that first part ("$1" means the first group) followed by " OR ".

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you're looking for something like this:

```
(?<=^([^"]*"[^"]*")+[^"|]*)\|
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks everyone.  Apologies for neglecting to mention this is in javascript and that terms don't have to be quoted, and there can be any number of quoted/unquoted terms, eg:

```
"this | that" | "the | other" | yet | another  -> "this | that" OR "the | other" OR yet OR another
```

Daniel, it seems that's in the ballpark, ie basically a matching/massaging loop.  Thanks for the detailed explanation. In js, it looks like a split, a forEach loop on the array of terms, pushing a term (after changing a | term to OR) back into an array, and a re join.

Answer (score 0):

@Alan M, works nicely, escaping not necessary due to the sparseness of sqlite FTS capabilities.

@epost, accepted solution for brevity and elegance, thanks. it needed to merely be put in a more general form for unicode etc.

```
(".+?"|[^\"\s]+)\s*\|\s*
```

Answer (score 0):

My solution in C# to count the quotes and then regex to get the matches:

```
        // Count the number of quotes.
        var quotesOnly = Regex.Replace(searchText, @"[^""]", string.Empty);
        var quoteCount = quotesOnly.Length;
        if (quoteCount > 0)
        {
            // If the quote count is an odd number there's a missing quote.
            // Assume a quote is missing from the end - executive decision.
            if (quoteCount%2 == 1)
            {
                searchText += @"""";
            }

            // Get the matching groups of strings. Exclude the quotes themselves.
            // e.g. The following line:
            // "this and that" or then and "this or other"
            // will result in the following groups:
            // 1. "this and that"
            // 2. "or"
            // 3. "then"
            // 4. "and"
            // 5. "this or other"
            var matches = Regex.Matches(searchText, @"([^\""]*)", RegexOptions.Singleline);
            var list = new List<string>();
            foreach (var match in matches.Cast<Match>())
            {
                var value = match.Groups[0].Value.Trim();
                if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(value))
                {
                    list.Add(value);
                }
            }

            // TODO: Do something with the list of strings.
       }
```